# Tensorflow will not run on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm a newbie when it comes to AWS and Tensorflow and I've been learning about CNNs over the last week via Udacity's Machine Learning course. 
Now I've a need to use an AWS instance of a GPU. I launched a p2.xlarge instance of Deep Learning AMI with Source Code (CUDA 8, Ubuntu) (that's what they recommended)

But now, it seems that tensorflow is not using the GPU at all. It's still training using the CPU. I did some searching and I found some answers to this problem and none of them seemed to work.

[image: <code>nvidia-smi</code> gives the following output:]

When I run the Jupyter notebook, it still uses the CPU

[image]

What do I do to get it to run on the GPU and not the CPU?

Comment: From the terminal, run the command `pip freeze | grep tensorflow` to determine whether the installed package is `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu`. It should be `tensorflow-gpu` to be able to utilize the GPU.

Comment: @T.Z that gave me the output: 

`tensorflow==1.4.1
tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1
tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0`

Comment: Most probably, your python environment is preferring tensorflow CPU version over the GPU one. I would suggest keeping only a single version rather than both the CPU and GPU version. Remove the CPU version of tensorflow by running the command `pip uninstall tensorflow`. If you are using python3, then use `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: Ok, I have tested the procedure and apparently, you have to reinstall `tensorflow-gpu` as well after removing `tensorflow`. It means you just have to execute `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu && pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: I did that and now it's throwing an error: 
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked a minor detail that you have to install version 1.4.1. So the command will be `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu && pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didnt help either. The error slightly changed: `ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: That should be expected. It means that the NVIDIA's cuDNN library, which is required by tensorflow GPU version, is not installed in the system. Install cuDNN version 6 (corresponding to CUDA 8.0) on the system to correctly run the tensorflow GPU version.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v6/prod/8.0_20170307/cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v6.0-tgz) is the download link of the required library. You have to login to NVIDIA developer account to download this file. Extract the downloaded archive and copy the files into corresponding folders inside the CUDA Toolkit install directory (usually `/usr/local/cuda`). Once copied, execute the command `ldconfig` (it may requires `sudo` privileges) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! Small problem, though. Like I said, I'm new to the whole AWS thing and I've managed to install everything I needed so far. But when I try `wget "scp -i ~/folder_key_pair/key_pair.pem ~/folder_tar_file/cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.0-ga.tgz ubuntu@public_dns_ec2:/home/ubuntu/"` I get a 403 forbidden error, which I'm guessing is because I have to login first. How do I do that from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, that is correct indeed. **403** is being shown because you have to login first. I would suggest that you download the file onto your local system and then copy it to AWS using `scp`.

Comment: @T.Z You have no idea how long I've been trying to get this to work. You, sir, are a blessing. It took me a while to get the copying done with my pathetic 50kbps upload speeds but it finally happened and the GPU is detected. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185745/discussion-between-pawan-bhandarkar-and-t-z).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem of tensorflow not detecting GPU can possibly be due to one of the following reasons.

1. Only the tensorflow CPU version is installed in the system.
2. Both tensorflow CPU and GPU versions are installed in the system, but the Python environment is preferring CPU version over GPU version.

Before proceeding to solve the issue, we assume that the installed environment is an [**AWS Deep Learning AMI**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) having CUDA 8.0 and tensorflow version 1.4.1 installed. This assumption is derived from the discussion in comments.

To solve the problem, we proceed as follows:

1. Check the installed version of tensorflow by executing the following command from the OS terminal.

> pip freeze | grep tensorflow

2. If only the CPU version is installed, then remove it and install the GPU version by executing the following commands.

> pip uninstall tensorflow
>
> pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1

3. If both CPU and GPU versions are installed, then remove both of them, and install the GPU version only.

> pip uninstall tensorflow
>
> pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
>
> pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1

At this point, if all the dependencies of tensorflow are installed correctly, tensorflow GPU version should work fine. A common error at this stage (as encountered by OP) is the missing cuDNN library which can result in following error while importing tensorflow into a python module

> ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory

It can be fixed by installing the correct version of NVIDIA's cuDNN library. Tensorflow version 1.4.1 depends upon cuDNN version 6.0 and CUDA 8, so we download the corresponding version from cuDNN archive page ([Download Link](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v6/prod/8.0_20170307/cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v6.0-tgz)). We have to login to the NVIDIA developer account to be able to download the file, therefore it is not possible to download it using command line tools such as `wget` or `curl`. A possible solution is to download the file on host system and use `scp` to copy it onto AWS.

Once copied to AWS, extract the file using the following command:

> tar -xzvf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v6.0.tgz

The extracted directory should have structure similar to the CUDA toolkit installation directory. Assuming that CUDA toolkit is installed in the directory `/usr/local/cuda`, we can install cuDNN by copying the files from the downloaded archive into corresponding folders of CUDA Toolkit installation directory followed by linker update command `ldconfig` as follows:

> cp cuda/include/* /usr/local/cuda/include
>
> cp cuda/lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
>
> ldconfig

After this, we should be able to import tensorflow GPU version into our python modules.

**A few considerations:**

- If we are using Python3, `pip` should be replaced with `pip3`.
- Depending upon user privileges, the commands `pip`, `cp` and `ldconfig` may require to be run as `sudo`.